# How to create setup for a Java application?

Tags: java, installation, desktop-application

I have developed an application in Netbeans which connects to a remote computer's message queue and sends messages. There are other features also for the application.  After the completion of the project I clean and build the application, then Netbeans creates a jar file.

But my problem is that how I will give the project to the customer?  I.E. the customer is less knowledge in computers so I had to give this application in a setup format so that if he clicked the setup it will automatically install the software needed and also takes default path of software if present.  Will anybody please help me how to do the above thing or any website that form the tutorial to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Launch4j is a cross-platform tool for wrapping Java applications distributed as jars in lightweight Windows native executables.

[Cross-platform Java executable wrapper](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

JSmooth creates native Windows launchers

[JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

[JSmooth User Manual](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting Windows, you can use something like exe4j (http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html)

> exe4j is a Java exe maker that helps you integrate your Java
>   applications into the Windows operating environment, whether they are
>   service, GUI or command line applications. If you want your own
>   process name instead of java.exe in the task manager and a user
>   friendly task-bar grouping in Windows XP, exe4j does the job. exe4j
>   helps you with starting your Java applications in a safe way,
>   displaying native splash screens, detecting or distributing suitable
>   JREs and JDKs, startup error handling and much more.

Answer (score 2):

There is also Java Web Start as another option, although instead of giving your customer a setup file you give him a link to a JNLP file that will install your application.

For more information, see [Java SE Desktop Technologies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html).

Comment: See also the [JWS info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for some great links about it.  JWS is supported by Oracle, & is cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a good old installer for your application you can use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net), there is even an [Ant task](http://nsisant.sourceforge.net) to integrate it to your build.

However look into Java Web Start first if your application suits this model, it will give you auto updating for free.